# How to handle date binding fail exception in springmvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson-databind

```
    @PostMapping("/subscribe/add")
    Subscribe add(@RequestBody Subscribe sub) throws BindException {
        return sub;
    }
```

`Subscribe` has a field:

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate subDate;
```

When i pass an invalid date, something like `"abc"`, i get `HttpMessageNotReadableException` exception. I can't get any useful message from `HttpMessageNotReadableException` that can send to client to tell user "you should pass a date like yyyy-MM-dd".

Answer (score 0):

A possibility can be to use an @ExceptionHandler to catch HttpMessageNotReadableException and transform it in more explicit HTTP code error and appropriate message

Something similar to this

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void handleIllegalArgument(HttpServletResponse res, Exception e)
        throws IOException {
    res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
}
```